# Spark streaming job scheduling controlling execution?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a problem where in spark streaming i am only concerned about last 1 minute so I have written my code accordingly

Now sometime due to various resource my scheduled batched got piled up like this

```
    INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1470046240000 ms
    INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1470046241000 ms
    INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1470046242000 ms
    INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1470046243000 ms
```

My question is how can I drop the schedule jobs if time exceed 1 minute 
so that they can be discarded before execution

Comment: It seems you given `batch interval` as `1 sec` increase this to `60 sec` and  see it solves your issue! Remember, your `processing time` should always be less than `batch interval`.

Comment: I have already done that its 50 sec 
problem is sometime there is more throughput  for a minute so more processing 

for that time jobs piles up because it has to be processed but if i can drop these jobs somehow again it will behave properly

Comment: I can see batch interval as `1 sec`(1000ms) from logs you provided above. However, IMO it is better to adjust `batch interval` accordingly instead of dropping the batches.

Comment: sorry for example above it was just for explanation 

lets say can we limit DAG scheduler  for making jobs if sudden burst happens as multiple partitions of my kafka  are creating jobs simultaneously

Comment: I understand now, but limiting number of jobs won't solve your problem! Can you provide processing times for following cases 1) min(when input size is minimum) 2) avg 3) max(when input size is high)?

Comment: input size is very much random that's why we cannot fixed any thing 
when it suddenly goes up we just don't want that  data to be processed 

so the timeline can move smoothly

Comment: Then you can try this, set threshold count and if your input RDD count is greater than threshold then just do nothing otherwise do all operations(like transformations, actions) you want. I use this approach for skipping empty batches.

Comment: Thanks  its seems this way is working  
can there be some thing  through which we can reschedule it for later time 

and let the system run smoothly now

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct way to reschedule the dropped batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to skip batches which have large input data then set threshold count and if your input RDD count is greater than threshold then just do nothing otherwise do all operations(like transformations, actions) you want.

I use this approach for skipping empty batches.